# MySQL tree structure with different data types in each node

Tags: mysql, tree

I'm aware of some strategies for building tree structures in MySQL, such as the adjacency list and nested Set, but I've never seen a way to build a tree where different nodes contain different data types. The only solution I can think of is using on of the tree paters together with EAV, but with all the downsides of EAV I was hoping that there might be a better solution.

Comment: What variety of data types are you thinking of?

Comment: @Uueerdo - Any data type and composites of data types. I want to store objects that have a fundamentally hierarchical relationship to each other. But those objects will be instance of different classes which are related by inheritance so each class will contain different types of data.